# RGBA Text alternative for IE 9. Can't get this work around to work

Tags: filter, opacity, css

the whole point of this is to have transparent text with a light white shadow to make the text look like it's embedded into the background. In all other browsers I simply do this to the text:

```
#mytext{
color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.7);
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
}
```

Works like a charm and gives it that great effect. IE, however... Well, you know how it is.

So I thought why not just make the div transparent and use the `Shadow` filter and we can all go home. Seemed clever at first, but Microsoft always seems to be one step ahead of me lol

```
 #mytext{
font-family: cowboyTimes;
font-size: 50px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
filter:alpha(opacity=90) Shadow(Color=#FFFFFF, Direction=180, Strength=1);
color: rgba(10, 10, 10, .7);
 }
```

I think I know what's happening here, I declare the alpha filter, then the shadow filter overwrites it, because if I rearrange the filters I get the last one on the list working. 
I've tried separating the m with commas, but there was no change at all. What am I doing wrong, or if there is a better way to do this I'm all ears (or eyes)!

Anyway, your help is appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#mytext{
font-family: cowboyTimes;
font-size: 50px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=90) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#FFFFFF, Direction=180, Strength=1)";
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=90) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#FFFFFF, Direction=180, Strength=1)";
color: rgba(10, 10, 10, .7);
 }
```

Comment: What if you have a much more complicated text-shadow?  

`{text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(102,204,255,.6), 1px 1px 1px rgba(51,153,204,.4), 0px -2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.15);}`

Can you just separate filters with commas?